# BLE performance issue on recent Android versions

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an Android app based on the sample project [BluetoothLeGatt](https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/index.html) provided by Google, that exchanges BLE data with another device.
Tests run on Android 4.3 (API 18 - Samsung Galaxy S3) worked fine, but when I tried it on Android 6.0 (API 23 - HTC One M8), I noticed significant performance issues: the BLE seems to slow down the application, which display haltingly the data received through notifications.

As I suppose that the HTC is more efficient, is it due to the BLE implementation on newer Android APIs? Or the sample project that is out of date?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It can also depend on the amount of scanning/reporting done. What happens if you run the BLE in a separate thread?

Comment: You should try your code on API level 19(kitkat)

Comment: The GATT server sends notifications to the app every 50 ms. For now I use the BluetoothLeService class from the google project, which is not a separate thread I think. I'm not sure how to proceed to run it in a separate thread.

I'm gonna try on API 19.

Thanks for the feedback

Comment: To be more precise about the version: the compiled sdk version is 23, the min sdk version is 18, and the target is 23 for now. I use the support library for the design and appcompat

Comment: I've tried to compile with a different API than 23, but I use the support design library, and it is not possible to use another version than the last one: "Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:19.0.0".

Comment: Did you use the new scan method for Lollipop and onwards? There were quite some changes in the scan API from Kitkat to Lollipop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @p2pkit. I use API 18 because my app needs to run on Jelly Bean devices. I think that the main issue does not come from the scan methods, because it happens when the device is connected (after the scan). I thought it could be due to low power optimizations parameters, but they are only available on API 21.

Comment: Usually you would set the minsdk version to 18 and the targetsdk version to 23. Then you can call the appropriate APIs based on build version checks. Anyways this seems not to be your problem. From your comment I got the impression, that your app slows down when you are connected and receive notifications. So you are probably doing too much work on the main thread, which slows down your app. Consider doing heavy work on a separated thread so your app stays responsive.

Comment: I could do that indeed, but I came to the same conclusion as you. The app begins lagging just a few seconds after the connection establishment. So I reduced the activity work to the minimum, and I noticed that the delay comes from the BLE service itself, which receives notifications from the API. I begin to think that this issue is out of my reach... especially as it works well on an older phone (Jelly Bean 4.3)

Comment: It seems like the ble callbacks are running on the main thread, which you cannot change, but you could do the work of the callbacks in another thread, did you try that?

Comment: I put the work of the onCharacteristicChanged() callback in another thread, but the issue remains. Thanks though. 
`new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
                }
            }).start();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Actually the issue didn't came from the Android "Central role" side. It came from the "Peripheral role" side played by my TI SensorTag, which updates automatically the connection parameters after 6 seconds, to go under some kind of low power mode (with a longer connection interval).
6 months later... that's never too late!